# Listening to UDP Datagrams using Java DatagramChannel

Tags: java, nio, datagram

I am trying to bind a Java DatagramChannel to listen to UDP traffic on a specific port and subinterface, but I cannot seem to get it to work on my linux host where I have created several virtual network subinterfaces (specifically the one I want to listen to is shown below). The code just fine if I host the java application in the same network Windows PC (using a different IP address however in that case for the bind call I simply had to specify the listening port and also on windows I do not use subinterfaces).

This is the relevant section output of ifconfig on my linux box showing the virtual network adapter( Subinterface )

```
p2p1:37: flags=4163<UP,BnetROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.34.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 192.168.255.255
        ether 00:13:72:a5:9c:e2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        device interrupt 16
```

The interface was setup as follows:

```
ifconfig p2p1:37 192.168.34.1 netmask 255.255.0.0
```

The code that I use to initialize the non blocking DatagramChannel is shown below: (I need a `DatagramChannel` as I need to use a selector to read from multiple ports simultaneously in a non blocking manner).  I tried binding to just the default adapter using the port number which is stored in in `entry.getValue()` via `channel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(entry.getValue())` but that did not receive any packets.  I read somewhere that after a DatagramChannel is constructed, it by default constructs a datagram socket that is bound to '0.0.0.0' and once bound it cannot be unbound - but I am not sure about any of that.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                updateMessage("Running...");
                Map<String, DatagramChannel> dlmuChannelInfo = new HashMap<>();
                Map<String, DatagramChannel> wsuChannelInfo =  new HashMap<>();
                try {
                    // array of bytes for receiving datagrams
                    ByteBuffer rxBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(MAX_PACKET_SIZE);

                    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : mDLMUPortInfo.entrySet()) {
                        DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
                        // select only works with nonblocking channels
                        channel.configureBlocking(false);

//                        NetworkInterface iface = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(
//                            InetAddress.getByName("192.168.34.1"));
//                        List<NetworkInterface> list = Collections.list(
//                            NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
//                        for (NetworkInterface next : list) {
//                        }

                        channel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(
                            InetAddress.getByName("192.168.34.1"), entry.getValue()));
                        dlmuChannelInfo.put(entry.getKey(), channel);
                    }

                    // register for reads
                    try (
                        // instantiate a selector - note that this autocloses
                        Selector selector = Selector.open()) {
                        // register a selector for reads for both the DLMU & WSU
                        Map<SelectionKey, String> keyServiceInfo = new HashMap<>();
                        for (Map.Entry<String, DatagramChannel> entry : dlmuChannelInfo.entrySet()) {
                            SelectionKey key = entry.getValue().register(
                                selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                            keyServiceInfo.put(key, entry.getKey());
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding to 192.168.34.1. You will only receive datagrams sent to that interface. Unless you really know what you're doing you should bind to 0.0.0.0, which is done by *omitting* the `InetAddress` parameter, or using null.

Your remark about `DatagramSocket` doing that itself on construction isn't correct.

Comment: @EJB I tried that and unfortunately it does not work, I have an FTP server also running at this virtual interface and I can login just fine so the IP address is alive and well.  The only issue I have encountered is due to the fact that it is a sub-interface.  I tried even enumerated through the subinterfaces and got the InetAddress from the specific sub-interface and used that to no avail.